# What does this math formula mean

Tags: probability

i am trying to learn statistical probability and encounter this formula. Someone please explain help me
$$\sum_{x}p(x)=1$$

Comment: It probably means "the sum over the probabilities of all $x$ is one", where the sum goes over all $x$ in your probability space. For example, for a coin toss this would look like $p(\text{heads}) + p(\text{tails}) = 1$

Comment: Please write your formula with MathJax notation rather than images

Comment: @Ruben Thank you very much

Comment: @David Sorry, my bad

Answer (score 6):

Here $p(x)$ denotes the probability of event $x$, and $\sum_x$ sums over mutually exclusive events, and $\sum_x p(x)=1$ says the probabilities sum to  $1$. This is an axiom in probability theory called unitarity.

Comment: thank you, i understand now

Comment: @user3391056 : To be more precise, it would be better to first define some (finite or countably infinite) set $\mathcal{X}$ over which the values $p(x)$ are defined, and then say $\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} p(x)=1$.

Comment: @Michael thank you for noticing that